# Что делать? Пишет такую ошибку:

Tags: android-studio, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AndroidProjects\Bomjara\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (Не удается найти указанный файл)
> C:\AndroidProjects\Bomjara\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (Не удается найти указанный файл)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Что делать?

Comment: Надо удалить папку: Проект/.gradle/2.8 тогда всё заработает :)
понял уже)

Comment: Напишите это в ответ

Answer (score 1):

У вас загадочным образом накрылся кэш Грейдла. Удаление директории `$project_root/.gradle` поможет (Грейдл перестроит кэши заново).